# GTK Portability - Linux libraries

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I've wrote a tool using GTK for a company project, however it seems that the entire GTK package or git is around 250mb and is required to compile.

This isn't a portable solution, to move 250mb to a machine, just to compile and then get rid of the library, so how do I go about making my program portable?

*This isn't a repeat question, I'm yet to find a solution on Linux.

Comment: How about compiling it on your machine, and distributing only your binaries to the target machine?

Comment: Well that part is fairly obvious, the worst of it, is that there are hundreds of files, and when I link my program to gtk I declare it like this: <gtk/gtk.h>.

So how is one meant to know, which libs are being used?

Comment: do a `ldd` on every binary (or library) you get by compiling, the output shows you the files needed to run your program

Comment: When you link your program to gtk, you're using somehing like -lgtk. Then, your library is using libgtk.so.xxx. You can prescribe the relevant OS package to be installed on the target machine. If you want a portable solution, you might have to prescribe what versions of the library is acceptable. Generally, you'll have to compile your program on a machine with the oldest version that you want to support. You'll probably have to do some research to know what versions of the library the major Linux distributions are installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to gengisdave in the question comments section; the solution is to use ldd.

In my case: ldd /dir/blablah/program_name - this produced an output like:

```
mikearmstrong@ubuntu:~/Desktop/linux_command_tool$ ldd ProntoCommandTool 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdb25f0000)
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007ffa4717f000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa46f2e000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa46c25000)
    libcups.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0x00007ffa469b1000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffa46793000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffa463cd000)
    libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007ffa46126000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa45f22000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ffa45d14000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ffa459df000)
```

and you can see that each library is declared within the return string.